# Firebase how to get NSDictionary data

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

I would like to get some data in user profile, I've got some info but I got stuck at this one.

Firebase database: [image]

Here is some of my code:

```
self.ref.child("users").child("profile").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {

            let user = User()

            let brands = dictionary["status"] as! NSDictionary


            user.displayname = dictionary["displayname"] as? String
            user.isconnected = brands["isconnected"] as? String

            print(user.isconnected) //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


class User: NSObject {
    var displayname: String?
    var isconnected: String?
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a `String` for `isconnected` ??? Replace `String` with `Boolean`. Keep using `[String: Any]` instead of `NSDictionary`

Comment: @Pipiks thanks for reply, I got errors changing to `Boolean` its says " Fix-it Replace with DarwinBoolen" , Could you please answer to the question and add some code? it will be more helpful.

Comment: Why the status contains the key E1D... and not directly the object ?

Comment: @Pipiks to see how many devices connected with same user, I was thinking to remove that, Ok i just removed it.

Comment: I updated my answer to keep that feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}

guard let statusDictionary = dictionary["status"] as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}

guard let deviceStatusDictionary = statusDictionary["DEVICE_KEY"] as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}

let user = User()

user.displayname = dictionary["displayname"] as? String
user.isconnected = deviceStatusDictionary["isconnected"] as? Bool
```

You need to know your device key.

And :

```
class User: NSObject {
    var displayname: String?
    var isconnected: Bool?
}
```

Comment: I did like what you just wrote, I'm getting "nil" for isconnected, I think the code doesn't accessed to isconnected, Any idea?

Comment: Thank you so much Pipiks! worked like charm. And i just removed device key maybe its useless.

Comment: You're welcome if it's important for your app keep it else remove it.